# For which <html> tag was the tag </html> in the footer.php closed?

Tags: php, html, css

I am reading << practical php and mysql building eight dynamic web applications>>.In the appendix A--web site design ,there are two files--header.php and footer.php.
It is the header.php file.

```
<?php
    require("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<head>
    <title><?php echo $config_sitename; ?></title>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <h1><?php echo $config_sitename; ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="<?php echo $config_basedir; ?>">Home</a>
        &bull;
        <a href="<?php echo $config_basedir; ?>about.php">About</a>
        &bull;
        <a href="<?php echo $config_basedir; ?>faq.php">FAQ</a>
        &bull;
        <a href="<?php echo $config_basedir; ?>tech.php">Technical Details</a>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="bar">
            <?php

                require("bar.php");
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
```

It is the footer.php file.

```
    </div>    
</div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

I have  two questions .
1.  why the tag in header.php don't close itself,such as

```
<div id="main">  don't close
<div id="container"> don't close
<body> tag don't close
```

All of them closed in the footer.php ,if the header.php is long and complicated,it is hard to write the footer.php file to close all the tags in the header.php.

2.There is a tag `</html>`   in the footer.php,but there is no `<html>` tag in the header.php,what is the matter?

Comment: Nothing is the matter, except the `header.php` file is missing an opening `<html>` tag. Welcome to the world of "other people's code", it is infested with poorly written code, bad application logic and typos that no-one else picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read that book but typically if a page is broken up into 3 parts :

header.php
content.php
footer.php

Then you can imagine the following block of HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <!--other content-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Being the same as this :

```
<!--header.php-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="main">
<!--header.php end-->

<!--content.php-->
        <!--other content-->
<!--content.php end-->

<!--footer.php-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<!--footer.php end-->
```

So for your first question, these tags can't be closed within header.php itself because that would not allow content from `content.php` to be inserted **within** the `.main` container.

For your second question, the `<html>` tag was probably left out accidentally.

A good practise is to include a comment beside the closing tag to make things clearer. For example, your `footer.php` could look like this :

```
    </div><!--#main-->
</div><!--#container-->
</body>
</html>
```

Doing so would prevent a lot of careless mistakes in case a tag was closed earlier than intended; or if the closing tag was missed out, you could spot it easily.